# Requests module not able to fetch data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a url `https://www.argos.co.uk/stores/api/orchestrator/v0/locator/availability?origin=RH10&skuQty=6217859_1` which holds a json data.

When I try to fetch it using requests module it seems never to get data and goes into infinite wait.

```
import requests

main = 'https://www.argos.co.uk/'
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'})
s.get(main)
url = 'https://www.argos.co.uk/stores/api/orchestrator/v0/locator/availability?origin=RH10&skuQty=6217859_1'
g = s.get(url)
print(g.content)
```

**Ctrl + x** on infinite loop:
[image: Where code breaks]

What can be the possible reason?
Note: hitting the url in the browser shows the data

Comment: I am getting the json data from that url with your code, check if your requests are updated or possibly restart your text editor. Your code is working fine for me.

Comment: @Insula tried on my VPS as well, didn't work

Comment: Can you please show the output you are getting?

Comment: @Insula program doesn't end, and keeps on running. and no output at all

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code and it is working fine. Try clicking Ctrl + X when it is in it's infinite loop, sometimes it stalls to output the data and that can speed it up. Also try a different text editor or update the one you are using.

Comment: That is strange.. did you try a different editor? Other than that I don't know what the problem is sorry.

Comment: Yep, tried a few, Code, Jupyter

Comment: I tried also on my pc, and on [repl](https://repl.it).it and it seems the same problem that happened to you also happens on my end. I tried also with curl and that worked fine.
So i copied the curl request from firefox, translated it to a python requests [onlinedevtools.in/curl](https://onlinedevtools.in/curl) but the problem still persists. This makes me think of a requests bug and you may want to downgrade or upgrade yours. @Insula what version of requests are you in ?  You can check by doing `print(requests.__version__)`

Comment: My requests version is 2.25.1